# when using hyperledger composer rest server, i get a validation error for empty arrays

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using the Hyperledger composer Rest server to try and create a participant.  I'm using http://localhost:3000 and trying to create the participant with a POST. 
 However, I keep getting a validation error for my array.

I can create the participant when i use the browser-based version of the composer.  I can also create the participant by calling composer from the command line (eg composer participant add ...)

```
participant User identified by email {
    o String name
    o String email
    --> Boat[] boats
}
```

And the error...

```
The 'User' instance is not valid.  Details: 'boats' can't be blank (value: [])
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm

I don't see this.

I've just set up a sample network.

and POSTed to an Asset which has an array `String[] test` field

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.biznet.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "ABC",
  "description": "string",
  "mainExchange": "ABC",
  "test": [
    "arrayelement1"
  ],
  "quantity": 20,
  "owner": "string"
}
```

In your model - the first element must be `email` as you've identified it as such. So then rebuild your .bna archive, and then update your business network (while making sure you stop any running REST server instances). Then try again. It should definitely work (there's nothing wrong with with the array elements).

Your second error points to the fact that - you've not provided any data to a required field.

Comment: To expand on the last point: Per default, every field in the model is required. You can only create a participant with a blank boat array if the boat array is defined as `Boat[] boats optional`